# For $n\ge 5,\forall e\neq\rho\in A_n,\exists\sigma=\alpha\rho\alpha^{-1}$ for some $α\in A_n$ s.t. $ρ(i)=σ(i)$ for some $i\in\{1,2,...,n\}$, but $ρ≠σ$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation, normal-subgroups, simple-groups

For $n\ge 5$, for all $e\neq \rho\in A_n, \exists \sigma=\alpha\rho\alpha^{-1}$ for some $\alpha\in A_n$ such that $\rho(i)=\sigma(i)$ for some $i\in\{1,2,...,n\}$, but $\rho\neq\sigma$.

The solution given is as follows:

> Let $(123...r)$ be the largest cycle in the disjoint cycle structure of $\sigma$. Let $r\ge 3$. Then $\sigma=(123456...r)\tau$. Let $ρ=(345)\sigma(354)=(124536...r)\alpha $ for some $\alpha $. Then $\sigma(1)=2=\rho(1)$. But $\sigma(2)=3\neq 4=\rho(2)$. So $\sigma\neq\rho$.
>
> Let $r=2$. Then $\sigma$ is a product of disjoint transpositions. Let there be at least $3$ transpositions. Then $\sigma=(12)(34)(56)\tau$. Let $\rho=(12)(35)\sigma(35)(12)=(12)(54)(36)\alpha$ for some $\alpha$. Then $\sigma(1)=2=\rho(1)$ and $\sigma(3)=4\neq 6=\rho(3)$. So $\sigma \neq \rho$.
>
> Finally, let $\sigma=(12) (34)$. Then $\rho=(132) (12)(34)(123)=(13)(24)$. So $\sigma(5)=5=\rho(5)$. But $\sigma\neq\rho$, as required.

However, I dont get how are they concluding "Then $\sigma=(123456...r)\tau$. Let $\rho=(345)\sigma(354)=(124536...r)\alpha $ for some $\alpha $". What is $\tau$ here? Also, how did they perform the calculation: $$\rho=(345)\sigma(354)=(124536...r)\alpha.$$

**EDIT 2:** ***After the benignant clarification by Hawaiian Earring Group***

I am confused about the solution for it says, "Let $(123...r)$ be the largest cycle in the disjoint cycle structure of $\sigma$", while there might not be any such cycle of $\sigma$. Again, I dont seem to understand the part following it i.e "Let $r=2$. Then $\sigma$ is a product of disjoint transpositions. Let there be at least $3$ transpositions. Then $\sigma=(12)(34)(56)\tau$. Let $\rho=(12)(35)\sigma(35)(12)=(12)(54)(36)\alpha$ for some $\alpha$." First of all, how does they assert $\sigma $ is a product of disjoint transpositions. If for a moment, we still consider $\sigma $ as a product of disjoint transpositions, but then what do they mean by "Let there be at least $3$ transpositions. Then $\sigma=(12)(34)(56)\tau$."? Next they say, "Let $\rho=(12)(35)\sigma(35)(12)=(12)(54)(36)\alpha$ for some $\alpha$." Didn't we just consider $\alpha$ as a variable previously to define $\sigma$ ? Then it does not make any sense to me.

Now, I am doubting the validity of the solution. Is it all valid? If not, can anyone suggest me a solution of this question.

I am not quite getting it...

Comment: Again: use, for example, `$\rho$` for $\rho$. Also use `$\in$` for $\in$.

Comment: Where did you find this proof?

Comment: @Shaun It was attached in a handout, maybe this was given in a regional text...the source is unknown to me apparently...

Comment: You seem to have used $\alpha $ twice,  in different roles. Otherwise,  wlog $(123456\dots r)$ is a generic $r$-cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\tau $ is just the permutation $(123456\dots r)^{-1}\sigma .$

The second answer is that conjugation preserves cycle structure. And we have, on an individual cycle, $a=(a_1a_2\dots a_s)$, that the conjugate by $b\in S_n$ is

$\boxed{bab^{-1}=(b(a_1)b(a_2)\dots b(a_s))}.$

So $$\rho:=(345)\sigma (354)=(345)(123456\dots r)\tau(354)=(345)(123456\dots r)(354)(345)\tau (354)=(124536\dots r)\alpha, $$ where $\alpha: =(345)\tau (354).$  This is because $(345)$ does the following: $3\to4,4\to5,5\to3.$

Comment: Thank you for your beningnant elucidation of the context. However, I have done a little amelioration to my post , mind taking a look at it ...

Comment: Sure.   I commented that they used $\alpha $ twice.   That's a mistake.   Other than that though,  remember that we are in $A_n.$  So $\sigma $ can't consist of just a single transposition (then it would be odd).  To address the choice of $(123456\dots r)$, as well as $(12)(34)$ and $(12)(34)(56)$, it's a simplifying assumption.   The cycle of length $r$ doesn't necessarily look exactly like that, but as far as the proof is concerned,  it would go through for any $r$-cycle.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding ! But what's the meaning of the line "Let there be $3$ transpositions..." as I quoted in my EDIT 2 , I dont get the context at all. Furthermore, I think the disjoint cycles $(12)(34)(56)$  can't be expressed as a single permutation  Is $\tau$ a transposition ? If so, then can we really make such a big assumption about $\sigma $ at the start of the solution...As I said earlier there might not be any such $r$ cycle in $\sigma$ ...Sorry if my questions demonstrates my stupidity ...but I don’t have a clue about this solution...

Comment: That's in the case where the cycle decomposition of $\sigma $ does not consist in just $2$ transpositions (but consists only in transpositions).  Also $(12)(34)(56)$ is certainly a permutation (just not a cycle).  $\tau $ is just the leftover there.

Comment: Ok, but if we consider the case when $r\neq 3$ , then how do they write $\sigma=(12)(34)(56)\tau$ out of nowhere, like where does $(12)(34)(56)\tau$ come from $(123...r)\tau$ , out of nowhere and also, $(123456)\neq (12)(34)(56)$ ...

Comment: What do you think about this? Can you possibly suggest a more legitimate solution of the problem ...It would really be helpful 

Comment: I do think it's correct.   Just a little hard to follow.   For instance,  they also transposed $\rho$ and $\sigma $ in the beginning.

Comment: Thank for your travail that you demonstrated for answering my questions with utmost equanimity. But I dont get from where $(12)(34)(56)$ in the expression $\sigma=(12)(34)(56)\tau$ come from ? Specifically, this and the expression $(12)(35)\sigma (35)(12)$ seem to pop out of nowhere!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142304/discussion-between-hawaiian-earring-group-and-franklin).